# Webdriver creates new session on every page

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver, session-cookies, acceptance-testing

Writing acceptance test for Magento 1.9 site using Codeception and Selenium-webdriver I got some issue.

Every time, when driver go to another page, for example clicks link and goes to product page or any other, new session starts. Magento "frontend" cookie get new value every time, so it's create a lot of problems. Troubles with adding item to cart, refusing payment. When I use site manualy, it's OK. Session still the same all the time. So problem is in webdriver. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

use "this" key work for using same instance for webdriver

ex.

```
@BeforeMethod
public void sample(WebDriver driver)
{`enter code here`
driver1-this.driver;
]
```

Comment: I am using webdriver via Codeception. But, I think I understood your post, but according to selenium-server logs, webdriver uses one instance for test.